# Is there a way to indent the first line of a paragraph in a R Markdown file

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, blogdown

I have a Rmd file hosted by `blogdown` 
I want to indent the first line of each paragraph, and have tried various things like `indent:True` inside the header, etc.

None of them seem to work and was wondering if anyone knew of a solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I assume that you have read [this appendix](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/css.html) of the `blogdown` documentation about CSS. If not, please read it first.*

Using `CSS`, you can use the [`text-indent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent).
For instance, you can add this CSS rule:

```
p {
  text-indent: 2rem;
}
```

It indents the first line of each paragraph.

Comment: where in the `main.css` file should I add your code chunk?

Comment: You can put it at the start of style.css